# Snakemake: Error while loading shared libraries - msub

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cluster-computing, snakemake

I have a problem when using Snakemake to submit jobs via msub on our MOAB cluster. Every time I run the test job using msub, the job fails and outputs the following error in the log file:

> /opt/***/common/devel/python/3.5.0/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The command I am using is

```
snakemake -j 10 --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "msub -q singlenode -l nodes={cluster.nodes}:ppn={cluster.ppn} -l pmem={cluster.pmem} -l walltime={cluster.time}" DECOMPRESS
```

The error is weird, as the required library is present in the path denoted in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
-bash: /opt/***/common/devel/python/3.5.2/lib: is a directory
$ ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
libpython3.5m.so  libpython3.5m.so.1.0  libpython3.so  pkgconfig  python3.5
```

When running the same test job directly on the login node (without using msub) the job also goes through perfectly, indicating that Snakemake is able to run in principle.

Do you think this is a problem of Snakemake or rather on the side of the cluster?

Cheers,
zuup

Comment: You'll have to wait for a MOAD expert to confirm, but from a cluster point of view, often the child nodes do not run the same environment as the parent or head node. The child nodes (on my SGE cluster), have to be explicitly passed via my qsub (msub equivalent). Try checking out the environments on the head node, where it runs, and right before it failed on a child node. [I believe the argument to see the environment is -v, perhaps -E passing the environment will help?](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/maui/commands/msub.php) I had similar issues in SGE, thus why I suggest this.

Comment: Great comment, did not think of that! Actually it was -V (exports all variables to the job) but this solved the problem! Is there a way to flag a comment as the solution? Otherwise you could maybe post it as a answer again.

Comment: You can also post your own answer, based on the indications given by @TBoyarski